# Create Unique Column Consisting of the Average of Multiple Columns with the same name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 400 column data frame with about 100 rows. Here is a head view of the data frame:

```
           MX      MX      ID      BR      MX      FR      BR      MX      ES      FR      ES      ES      MX      FR
2/19/2015  111.45  122.46   98.16  101.20   98.60  100.74   93.15   98.61  110.69  102.28  143.21  135.32  103.30   98.50
2/12/2015  110.71  123.50   98.60  100.97   98.00  100.67   93.18   99.84  110.57  102.33  141.50  136.04  102.63   99.25
2/5/2015   111.51  125.27   99.25  101.27   97.75  100.83   93.38  101.09  111.62  102.30  145.76  137.74  102.50   96.75
1/29/2015  111.00  122.25   99.63  101.25   99.20  100.63   93.06   98.69  111.59  102.47  142.75  138.61  101.88   96.25
1/22/2015  111.39  124.00   98.13  100.55   98.92  100.52   93.00  100.21  108.99  102.46  140.96  134.14  101.75   95.75
1/15/2015  111.11  121.37   97.38  100.35   99.75  100.66   93.00  101.11  109.50  102.48  143.03  131.35  101.50   95.45
```

I need to create a column that is the average of all columns with that column name, so I have 1 column "MX" that is the average of all MX on 2/19/2015, and the same for ID, BR, FR, etc.

Comment: Maybe you can use *colMeans*.  Check [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html) for more details and example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to using `$dollarsign` notation to reference columns in your dataframe, this sort of format can be daunting. However, bear in mind that each column can still be referred to unambiguously using its index.

For your specific case ,you can figure out which columns have a given name using `names`, and pass these indices to `colMeans`:

```
df$MX.mean <- rowMeans(df[which(names(df) == "MX")])
```

If you want to do this for every name appearing in the dataframe, here's a quick hack. Note that this is probably not the most efficient or elegant solution; loops can almost always be avoided in R.

```
for (name in unique(names(df))){
  mean.col <- rowMeans(df[which(names(df) == name)])
  df[paste(name, ".mean")] <- mean.col
}
```

Finally, your life may be easier if you can avoid this problem in the first place and make sure your data are more logically named.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `mapply` with `rowMeans`

```
  nm1 <- unique(names(df1))
  res <-  mapply(function(x,y) rowMeans(df1[x == y], na.rm=TRUE),
                        list(names(df1)), nm1)
  colnames(res) <- paste0(nm1, '.Mean')
  res
  #         MX.Mean ID.Mean BR.Mean   FR.Mean  ES.Mean
  #2/19/2015 106.884   98.16  97.175 100.50667 129.7400
  #2/12/2015 106.936   98.60  97.075 100.75000 129.3700
  #2/5/2015  107.624   99.25  97.325  99.96000 131.7067
  #1/29/2015 106.604   99.63  97.155  99.78333 130.9833
  #1/22/2015 107.254   98.13  96.775  99.57667 128.0300
  #1/15/2015 106.968   97.38  96.675  99.53000 127.9600
```

`cbind` the output ("res") with original dataset.  In that way, the column names in "df1" would not change.

```
df1 <- cbind(df1, res)
head(df1,2)
#          MX     MX    ID     BR   MX     FR    BR    MX     ES     FR
#2/19/2015 111.45 122.46 98.16 101.20 98.6 100.74 93.15 98.61 110.69 102.28
#2/12/2015 110.71 123.50 98.60 100.97 98.0 100.67 93.18 99.84 110.57 102.33
#           ES     ES     MX    FR   MX.Mean ID.Mean BR.Mean  FR.Mean ES.Mean
#2/19/2015 143.21 135.32 103.30 98.50 106.884   98.16  97.175 100.5067  129.74
#2/12/2015 141.50 136.04 102.63 99.25 106.936   98.60  97.075 100.7500  129.37
```

Or convert the `wide` format to `long` format and then reconvert it back to `wide`.

```
 library(reshape2)
 library(splitstackshape)
 res <- dcast.data.table(getanID(melt(as.matrix(df1)), 1:2)[,
      Var2:=paste0(Var2, '.Mean')], Var1~Var2, value.var='value', mean)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(MX = c(111.45, 110.71, 111.51, 111, 111.39, 
 111.11
 ), MX = c(122.46, 123.5, 125.27, 122.25, 124, 121.37), ID = c(98.16, 
 98.6, 99.25, 99.63, 98.13, 97.38), BR = c(101.2, 100.97, 101.27, 
 101.25, 100.55, 100.35), MX = c(98.6, 98, 97.75, 99.2, 98.92, 
 99.75), FR = c(100.74, 100.67, 100.83, 100.63, 100.52, 100.66
 ), BR = c(93.15, 93.18, 93.38, 93.06, 93, 93), MX = c(98.61, 
 99.84, 101.09, 98.69, 100.21, 101.11), ES = c(110.69, 110.57, 
 111.62, 111.59, 108.99, 109.5), FR = c(102.28, 102.33, 102.3, 
 102.47, 102.46, 102.48), ES = c(143.21, 141.5, 145.76, 142.75, 
 140.96, 143.03), ES = c(135.32, 136.04, 137.74, 138.61, 134.14, 
 131.35), MX = c(103.3, 102.63, 102.5, 101.88, 101.75, 101.5), 
 FR = c(98.5, 99.25, 96.75, 96.25, 95.75, 95.45)), .Names = c("MX", 
"MX", "ID", "BR", "MX", "FR", "BR", "MX", "ES", "FR", "ES", "ES", 
"MX", "FR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2/19/2015", 
"2/12/2015", "2/5/2015", "1/29/2015", "1/22/2015", "1/15/2015"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `vapply()`

```
vapply(
    unique(names(df)), 
    function(x) rowMeans(df[grepl(x, names(df), fixed = TRUE)]),
    double(nrow(df))
)
#                MX    ID     BR        FR       ES
# 2/19/2015 106.884 98.16 97.175 100.50667 129.7400
# 2/12/2015 106.936 98.60 97.075 100.75000 129.3700
# 2/5/2015  107.624 99.25 97.325  99.96000 131.7067
# 1/29/2015 106.604 99.63 97.155  99.78333 130.9833
# 1/22/2015 107.254 98.13 96.775  99.57667 128.0300
# 1/15/2015 106.968 97.38 96.675  99.53000 127.9600
```

where `df` is

```
df <- read.table(check.names = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = "MX      MX      ID      BR      MX      FR      BR      MX      ES      FR      ES      ES      MX      FR
2/19/2015  111.45  122.46   98.16  101.20   98.60  100.74   93.15   98.61  110.69  102.28  143.21  135.32  103.30   98.50
2/12/2015  110.71  123.50   98.60  100.97   98.00  100.67   93.18   99.84  110.57  102.33  141.50  136.04  102.63   99.25
2/5/2015   111.51  125.27   99.25  101.27   97.75  100.83   93.38  101.09  111.62  102.30  145.76  137.74  102.50   96.75
1/29/2015  111.00  122.25   99.63  101.25   99.20  100.63   93.06   98.69  111.59  102.47  142.75  138.61  101.88   96.25
1/22/2015  111.39  124.00   98.13  100.55   98.92  100.52   93.00  100.21  108.99  102.46  140.96  134.14  101.75   95.75
1/15/2015  111.11  121.37   97.38  100.35   99.75  100.66   93.00  101.11  109.50  102.48  143.03  131.35  101.50   95.45")
```